# Everything in c++ by default is passed by value

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

In C++, are all types passed by value unless it comes with a `&` or `*` symbol?

For example in Java, passing an array as a function argument would be by default passing by reference. Does C++ give you more control over this?

**EDIT**: Thanks for all your responses, I think I understand the whole pass-by-value thing more clearly. For anyone who is still confused about how Java passes by value (a copy of the object reference), [this answer really cleared it up for me.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12429953/5909227)

Comment: Even in java, objects are passed by value. Ideally, considering objects as passing by reference makes it more understandable and that may be the reason why some books and references have called passing objects as `pass by reference`. Java follows pass by value and there is nothing like `pass by reference` in it.

Comment: In the case of passing an array, C++ provides vector as another option. I just put this sentance in the wrong place, to all the down-voters.

Comment: I would refrain from saying terms like "value" and "reference" when comparing two languages and how they handle parameters.  Those terms for C++ mean specific things.  Those terms for Java mean specific things.  For another language, again, specific things.

Comment: In Java, a "reference" is a kind of value, and the word "reference" used to refer to these values has nothing to do with "pass by reference". "Pass by reference" and "pass by value" refer to whether a function is passed a reference to a variable or the value of a variable.

Comment: Note that C++11 added `&&` to the mix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> In C++, are all types passed by value unless it comes with a & or *
>   symbol?

No if you pass something as * parameter (a pointer thereof) it is still passed by **value**. A copy of the pointer being passed is made. But both the original and copy point to the same memory. It is similar concept in C# - I believe also in Java, just you don't use * there.

That is why if you make changes to the outer objects using this pointer (e.g. using dereferencing), changes will be visible in original object too.

But if you just say assign a new value to the pointer, nothing will happen to the outer object. e.g.

```
void foo(int* ptr)
{
  // ...
  // Below, nothing happens to original object to which ptr was 
  // pointing, before function call, just ptr - the copy of original pointer - 
  // now points to a different object 
  ptr = &someObj; 
  // ...
}
```

> For example in Java, passing an array as a function argument would be
>   by default passing by reference. Does C++ give you more control over
>   this?

In C++ or C if you pass array (e.g. `int arr[]`), what is being passed is treated as pointer to the first element of the array. Hence, what I said above holds true in this case too.

About & you are correct. You can even apply & to pointers (e.g., `int *&`), in which case now, the pointer indeed gets passed by reference - there is no copy made.

Comment: `actually what is being passed is treated as pointer` This holds true for java too. Java also has nothing like pass by reference.

Comment: @MathewsMathai I was making changes, you can cross check

Comment: Well, I was just mentioning. No offence.

Comment: Don't forget that you can actually pass arrays by reference in C++.

Answer (score 5):

Probably tangential to your question, but I often take another direction to understand what happens when you call a function in C++.

The difference between

```
void foo(Bar bar);  // [1]
void foo(Bar& bar); // [2]
void foo(Bar* bar); // [3]
```

is that the body in `[1]` will receive a **copy** of the original bar (we call this *by value*, but I prefer to think of it as *my own copy*).

The body of `[2]` will be working with the exact same `bar` object; no copies. Whether we can modify that `bar` object depends on whether the argument was `Bar& bar` (as illustrated) or `const Bar& bar`. Notice that in a well-formed program,`[2]` will always receive an object (no `null` references; let's leave dangling references aside).

The body of `[3]` will receive a copy of the pointer to the original `bar`. Whether or not I can modify the pointer and/or the object being pointed depends on whether the argument was `const Bar* bar`, `const Bar* const bar`, `Bar* const bar`, or `Bar* bar` (yes, really). The pointer may or may not be `null`.

The reason why I make this mental distinction is because a copy of the object may or may not have reference semantics. For example: a copy of an instance of this class:

```
struct Foo {
 std::shared_ptr<FooImpl> m_pimpl; 
};
```

would, by default, have the same "contents" as the original one (a new shared pointer pointing to the same `FooImpl` pointer). This, of course, depends on how did the programmer design the class.

For that reason I prefer to think of `[1]` as "takes a copy of bar", and if I need to know whether such copy will be what I want and what I need I go and study the class directly to understand what does that class in particular means by *copy*.